# How to get Type of Array in Typescript generics

Tags: typescript

I have a method like this:

```
public select(fieldName: keyof TType)
```

Where `TType` could be an array type.  In case of an array type, `fieldName` will correctly offer me all the propertynames of type `Array`.

In case I call this method with a type of `User[]` I want to get to the properties of `User` instead of the properties of `Array`.

Is there any way of how this could be done?

Extra question: Is there any way to restrict TType to be of an array type?

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible since `User[]` is an array, and it has no properties unique to `User` since an array is just a container of other information, and the typings are just part of TS and not part of JS.  

The best I can suggest is to add something to look at the first item in the array and determine the properties on it, or the type there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can definitely make a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type function that unwraps an array type up to one level deep, and then use `keyof` on the result of that.  For example:

```
// unwrap up to one level
type Unarray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;

// your class maybe
declare class Thingy<T> {
  constructor(t: T);
  public select(fieldName: keyof Unarray<T>): void;
}
// your interface maybe
interface User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

declare const u1: User;
declare const u2: User;
const x = new Thingy(u1);
x.select("name"); // okay
const y = new Thingy([u1, u2]);
y.select("age"); // okay
y.select("push"); // error
```

That should work as you want, for the typings, I think.  Obviously you also need to have an implementation which works (and note that conditional types in implementations usually require some type assertions or overloads to make the compiler happy... but you seem to be asking about the typings, not the implementation).

---

As for your extra question, yes, you can restrict `T` to just array types, as follows:

```
// your class maybe
declare class Thingy<T extends Array<any>> {
  constructor(t: T);
  public select(fieldName: keyof (T[number])): void;
}
// your interface maybe
interface User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

declare const u1: User;
declare const u2: User;
const x = new Thingy(u1); // error
const y = new Thingy([u1, u2]);
y.select("age"); // okay
```

Note that I did away with the conditional types altogether here because it's more straightforward.

Comment: Great! Works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You will need a little helper to extract the boxed type:

```
type Unboxed<T> =
    T extends (infer U)[]
        ? U
        : T;
```

Then your method can look like this:

```
interface User {
    id: symbol;
    name: string;
}

class Foo {
    select(fieldName: keyof Unboxed<User[]>) {
        console.log(fieldName) // "id" | "name"
    }
}
```

As to your extra question: yes, it's possible, but it may feel a bit strange.

```
class Foo {
    select<T extends any[]>(fieldName: keyof Unboxed<T>) {
        console.log(fieldName)
    }
}

new Foo()
  .select<Window[]>('addEventListener')
```

Type parameters are meant to describe the arguments living inside the method or the generic type of the class. So perhaps you wanted to do the following:

```
class Foo<T extends any[]> {
    select(fieldName: keyof Unboxed<T>) {
        console.log(fieldName)
    }
}

new Foo<Window[]>()
  .select('addEventListener')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is also a valid answer, but it was the second answer, thats why I marked jcalz's answer.

Answer (score 4):

One can determine the type parameter `T` from an array of type `type U = T[]` by indexing by number, eg., `U[number]`.

```
type Foo = {"foo": string};
type Bar = {"bar": number};
type FooArray = Foo[];
type BarArray = Bar[];

FooArray[number]; // {"foo": string}
BarArray[number]; // {"bar": number}
```

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=12&pln=2&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvARAMwegXFAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChRIoAhAQ2OTXQCMO8o5AK4BbHhGJ1G4aPDgBBYsTYgucgNoBdBk2jtii5apT6tDacxhqEhleuFiJ2qAHoXsBBb1d9tkPdFxYmc3Vg4gA) with the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TType[0]` as the type is working for me in practice. So, in your example:

```
public select(fieldName: keyof TType[0])
```

As ugly as that is, it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Fist of why do you use the operator `keyof` ? that leads to an array in each case since fieldName will be only the keys in the `TType` type.

If you want an array of `User` you need to define `TType` as such:

```
type TType = User[]
...
public select(fieldName: TType) {
   ...
}
```

If you wish `TType` to be any array you will define it as such
    type TType = any[]

but in the second defintion typescript won't be able to infer the inner type (in this case `User` which is not what you want i presume.

Finally if `TType` could be multiple type of arrays:
    type TType = User[] | Whatever[] | ...

If you want a more detail answer please provides a better explanation of what you want.
In the meantime i hope this helps ;)
Seb