# Selecting Nested Typescript Type Generics Inside Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have the following generated type from a GraphQL query.

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null

...

export type DealFragmentFragment = { __typename: "Deal" } & Pick<
  Deal,
  "id" | "registeringStateEnum" | "status" | "offerStatus"
> & {
    users: Maybe<Array<{ __typename: "User" } & Pick<User, "id" | "name">>>
    >
```

I have a React function that takes a User passed down from the above query.

```
function userCard({ user }) {
   // ...do stuff
}
```

My question is how do I select the User subset from `DealFragmentFragment`?

```
function userCard({ user }: { user: DealFragmentFragment["users"] }) {
   // ...do stuff
}
```

What goes after `DealFragmentFragment["users"]` to get "inside" of the array and Maybe to show the `id` and `name` properties?

Thank you!

Comment: If you `console.log(DealFragmentFragment["users"])` what do you see?

Comment: Hi @ManoshTalukder.  It's an error.  I don't believe `console.log` evaluates TS types.

The compiler for the above code states `TypeScript error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Maybe<({ __typename: "User"; } & Pick<User, "id" | "name">)[]>'.  TS2339`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed a helper...

```
type Unarray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;
```

Then...

```
function userCard({ user }: {user: Unarray<DealFragmentFragment["users"]> }) {
   // ...do stuff
}
```

Now `user` shows properties `id` and `name`.  Thanks to [How to get Type of Array in Typescript generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782721/how-to-get-type-of-array-in-typescript-generics)

If anyone has a better solution, please post it and I'll accept it.  But otherwise this worked for me!

Comment: Thank you!!! I had a similar issue with some `urql/prisma/nexus` generation and had the exact same question, and your `Unarray` solved it!  Extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the type of nested element from array, you can do this:

```
// Let's assume the following is your result array:
const result = [{user: {id: 1, name: "abc"}}];
type t1 = typeof result // this will give you the type of the array
type t2 = typeof result[0] // This will give you the type of the element in the array.

type userId = typeof result[0][0] // Gives you the first key of the first element of the array.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply!  `DealFragementFragment["users"][0]` returns `Property '0' does not exist on type 'Maybe<({ __typename: "User"; } & Pick<User, "id" | "name">)[]>'.ts(2339)`